Getting function arg info from a signature in text form
Given a string like this one:
signature = "func(data: list[str], opt = None) -> int"

How do I get the argument details (and also the function return type) ?
# name    type hint    default
# ----    ---------    -------
# data    list[str]    -
# opt     -            None


I have tried to play with ast:
funcdef = f"def {signature}: pass"
print(ast.dump(ast.pars(funcdef), indent=2))

but this annotation does not look like 'list[str]' at all:
arg='data',
annotation=Subscript(
  value=Name(id='list', ctx=Load()),
  slice=Name(id='str', ctx=Load()),
  ctx=Load())),

I think I could use eval to create a real func object and inspect it, but I'm afraid of possible side effects.
